CSS not working after applying collectstatic in Django
I just deployed my django project on nginx server. I have connected with domain and everything, site is live. However, the issue occured when I used python3 manage.py collectstatic. Everything still works, but css is not loaded and site is not looking how it supposed to be.
Here is some code and options that I tried.
parts from settings.py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my-wow-site.com', 'www.my-wow-site.com', 'xx.xx.xxx.xx']

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

urls.py
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path(_('admin/'), admin.site.urls),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('', include('main_app.urls', namespace='main_app')),
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

I have everything uploaded/deployed in root folder... and I have set up this by using command
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

content is...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-wow-site.com www.my-wow-site.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    root /root/wow_site/

    location /static/ {
        alias /root/wow_site/staticfiles/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /root/wow_site/media/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-wow-site.com www.my-wow-site.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Usually sources from internet, guide me to set this up (below) which I did.
    location /static/ {
        alias /root/wow_site/staticfiles/;
    }

Not sure what else I could do or what I made mistake. Any help is more than welcomed. Thanks in advance!

you use https connetion but allow static only http connection.
so, i think problem is..
need change config and restart nginx.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-wow-site.com www.my-wow-site.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-wow-site.com www.my-wow-site.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /static/ {
        alias /root/wow_site/staticfiles/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /root/wow_site/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

